# Match a View in WebView from Espresso in Android

Tags: android, salesforce, android-webview, android-espresso

I want to match the user name text field inside a WebView which loads the Salesforce login page (but can also be applied to any other page with text fields).

[image]

I have tried with:

```
onView(withHint("User Name")).perform(typeText("test@sf.com"));
```

But that doesn't work. Any better idea?

Comment: Did any one try with Espresso 2.2 Web APIs to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished using Espresso Web 2.2 API

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID,"username")).perform(webKeys("test@sf.com"));
```

Comment: What if I dont know Locator ID and only Hint(of the TextView), for example "User Name"?

Comment: this above code working fine with above mentioned website. Thanks for your logic.           I have tried with some other website, its not working for me. is there any restriction for specific public domain website? please update. I have tried www.google.com to click Sign in button. not working for me. can you please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Locator.Xpath if you don't know ID.
To find xpath first you need to check the html code based on which you can write xpath.
 To get html source code you can use chrome inspector. 
connect the device to the PC and then open chrome inspector.You can right click on the html code and click on copy xpath to get the xpath.

Comment: can we apply this xPath logic for any public domain website. ex: www.google.com page contains Sign in button.   can we try signin button for BDD webview  auto click.                is there any restriction for websites?

Answer (score 0):

You can fill form just run js code in WebView.
For example:

```
webView.loadUrl("
   javascript:document.getElementById('username-field').value = 'test@sf.com’;
");
```